# elpy not picking up virtualenv

Tags: elpy, virtualenv

I use elpy with:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "/usr/bin/python3")
(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")
```

I need now to work on a virtuaelnv. If I start it in a terminal and then edit the source code with emacs, elpy does not pick up the virtualnev.

Looking at the documentation I'm confused: do I need pyenv (and pyenv-mode?) or anything else?

Comment: If it hasn't changed in the last month, you need it. I can recommend pyvenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution for me was:

1. install virtualenvwrapper
2. create virtualen
3. run `pyvenv-workon` and select the desired environment.

Gotchas:

1. make sure that emacs sees the correct workon dir: `(getenv "WORKON_HOME")` (read from ~/.profile)
2. make sure that python-shell-interpreter is not set in your .emacs -- if it is, then it will override whatever pyvenv you are using.
3. make sure that the virtualenv python (/bin inside the virtualenv dir) is the same you see in emacs (inspect with `M-x elpy-config` (both for `RPC Python` and `Interactive Python` options)).

Answer (score 4):

To work on a virtual environment, you need to call `M-x pyvenv-workon` and then select the preferred working environment.

There is no need to install other packages as elpy comes with pyvenv package.